# how to set currentUser displayName, and other criteria to retrieve current user information

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to fetch the information of the current user in firebase and I am having a hard time wondering where to state what the current user's name should be and how to pull that information?

I have looked at the documentation but it just states what it does instead of stating how to set the information of displayName or email?

Do I set the display name to my `const name = document.getElementById('name).value` where I would state something along that of

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        const displayName = name;
    } else {
        console.log('not signed in)
    }
});
```

In my registration.js and then when I want to pull the displayName of the user in a different js file after I initialized it with firebase how would I use that information?

Thank you!

Comment: the `user` passed by `.onAuthStateChanged` is an object. You can see `displayName`, `email`, and much more in the console. Just do `console.dir(user);` inside your `.onAuthStateChanged` to see it all.

Answer (score 1):

To get the user's display name:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
    console.log(user.displayName);
   } else {
    console.log('not signed in');
   }
});
```

To set the user's display name:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.updateProfile({
  displayName: "Jaffer Abyan Syed",
}).then(function() {
  console.log("Display name updated");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error)
});
```

Comment: I get the "Cannot read property 'updateProfile' of null" and for some reason. Is there a way I can set it up while I am trying to have a user register ?

Comment: That message means there is no current user. If you want to prevent that problem, you can put the same code inside the `onAuthStateChanged` callback. `if (user) { user.updateProfile({ ... })...`.